# Store N^(n*n) matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Every time I find a pretty good solution to a problem at my work, always start coding in C to ruin that feeling... :D

So here I am, noobing with some easy C code and wonder why it's not working o.O
I want to represent a matrix with a 2D array (array of arrays) and fill it from a text file. The code is bad, the code ugly... I'm interested any tip/trick what I can fetch from you, Mr. senior :)

What wrong with my logic? What is under the hood? Am I using the `[]` operator not as expected? Am I just simply don't know how to iterate through a 2D array? I complie this source on windows with cl, using declaration in `for()` and god know what else what is not strictly C-like.

Input is a text file containing the size of the matrix and the elements of it separated by white space(s). The syntax of this: file := {n, A | n :-N, A := N^(n*n)}

For example:

```
3
1 3 2
4 5 2
7 0 1
```

So here it is... take cover!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

Opening the file, no error checking for the minimal code :)

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("mat_mul.test", "r");
```

Now, allocating the arrays based on the first integer in the file... Is this correct? Are there any better approach for allocating array of arrays?

```
    int n = fgetc(fp) - '0';
    int **A = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        A[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
```

Aaand, here is the magic, the spell what has turned against its master :D

```
    char act;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (EOF != (act = fgetc(fp)))
        if ('0' <= act && '9' >= act)
            A[j == n - 1 ? i++ : i][j == n - 1 ? j = 0 : j++] = act - '0';

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("A[%i][%i]=%i\n", i, j, A[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Cleaning without exhaustive!

```
    if (fclose(fp)) {

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start with `char act;`-> `int act;`

Comment: Also [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) reads, as you seem to know, a single character. Guess how many characters are on the first line? Not one, but *two*, you forget the newline. I suggest learning to use a debugger, so you can step through the code while at the same time being able to monitor the values of all variables.

Comment: But it will be ignored due to the if() in every iteration, or am I wrong?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please note that open ended questions like "what do you think about this code" are not suitable for Stackoverflow. SO works best if you ask a *specific* question.

Comment: Totaly aggree on that, and already found a possible bug: while filling the arrays I use the glory of the postfix `++` operator, but when I have to make the second dimension 0, it do it on the 1-1. not after the assignment. My question was: Is my dynamic array handling wrong, or the algrorithm. I think the algorithm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke undefined behaviour when you try to do the row and column assignment and advancement at once here:

```
A[j == n - 1 ? i++ : i][j == n - 1 ? j = 0 : j++] = act - '0';
```

You assign to `j` in the second pair of brackets and also access its value in the first pair. (My compiler warns me that the "operation on 'j' may be undefined".) There is a sequence point between the parts of the ternary operatoy, but not between the two index operators `[]`.

Besides the undefined behaviour, the expression is also needlessly complicated in my opinion. Separate assignmemt and advancing the row and columns counter:

```
    if ('0' <= act && '9' >= act) {            
        A[i][j] = act - '0';

        j++;
        if (j == n) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
            if (i == n) break;    // end outer while
        }
    }
```

You should also include `<stdlib.h>` for the declaration of  `malloc`. (That's also something my compiler tells me when warnings are enabled.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and your opinion on my code as well. It really help me a lot to make a proper C code!